# How to terminate a process in io:get_line?

Tags: erlang

Let's say I have a process p1 and p2. When p1 ends, I also want p2 to end (p2 is waiting for an input from the user using `io:get_line()` when p1 ends). I can successfully end p1 by just letting the function end itself (no more code to execute), but how am I suppose to end p2 that is waiting for an input using p1?

These are the codes for the two processes:

```
chat1(2,Chat_Node,Name) ->
    timer:sleep(100),
    Message = io:get_line(io_lib:format("~s: ", [string:strip(Name,right,$\n)])),
    case re:replace(Message, "\\s+", "", [global,{return,list}]) == [$b,$y,$e] of
        true -> 
            Chat_Node ! bye;
        false -> 
            Chat_Node ! {Name, Message},
            chat1(2, Chat_Node, Name)
    end.

chat2(2,Chat_Node,Name) ->
    timer:sleep(100),
    Message = io:get_line(io_lib:format("~s: ", [string:strip(Name,right,$\n)])),
    case re:replace(Message, "\\s+", "", [global,{return,list}]) == [$b,$y,$e] of
        true -> 
            {msg1, Chat_Node} ! bye;
        false -> 
            {msg1, Chat_Node} ! {Name, Message},
            chat2(2, Chat_Node, Name)
    end.
```

After receiving an input from the user, the message is sent to the processes msg1 and msg2(Chat_Node). If the message is "bye", the process that has "bye" will end.

Answer (score 2):

the process `P1` can monitor the process `P2` using the function: `MonitorRef = erlang:monitor(process, P2)`

Doing so, it will receive the message `{'DOWN', MonitorRef, process, P2, Reason}` when `P2` will terminate and then perform the appropriate actions before finishing.

Note: a link wouldn't work if P2 ends normally (no more code to execute). It could work if P2 exits with another reason than `normal`

**Edit**

A small example in the shell (need to adapt in a module)

```
1> F = fun() -> io:format("Hello~n"),timer:sleep(2000) end.
#Fun<erl_eval.20.52032458>
2> G = fun() -> P2 = spawn(F),                                                                    
2>     MonitorRef = erlang:monitor(process,P2),                                                       
2>     io:format("P1 waiting for P2 end~n"),                                                          
2>     receive                                                                                        
2>         {'DOWN', MonitorRef, process, P2, Reason} -> io:format("P2 finished with reason ~p~n",[Reason])
2>     end,                                                                                           
2>     io:format("P1 got message from P2~n")                                                          
2>     end.                                                                                           
#Fun<erl_eval.20.52032458>
3> spawn(G).                                                                                      
P1 waiting for P2 end
Hello
<0.73.0>
P2 finished with reason normal
P1 got message from P2
4>
```

**Edit 2**

in this new example P2 get a float and transmit it to P1. if the input is a float, P2 exits with reason normal after sending the message `{ok,Value}` to P1 which in turn returns only Value. If the conversion from string to float fails, P2 exits with an error message which is catch by the second clause in the receive block. P1 recall itself (silly error management, just for illustration :o)

```
1> F = fun(From) -> 
1>     String = io:get_line("enter a float : "),
1>     Float = list_to_float(string:strip(String,both,$\n)),
1>     From ! {ok,Float}
1> end.
#Fun<erl_eval.20.52032458>
2> G = fun G() ->
2>     P1 = self(),
2>     P2 = spawn(fun() -> F(P1) end),
2>     MonitorRef = erlang:monitor(process,P2),
2>     receive
2>         {ok,Float} -> Float;
2>         {'DOWN', MonitorRef, process, P2, Reason} ->
2>             io:format("this is not a float!"),
2>             G()
2>     end
2> end.
#Fun<erl_eval.20.52032458>
3> G().
enter a float : 5.2
5.2
4> G().
enter a float : hello
this is not a float!
=ERROR REPORT==== 3-Oct-2016::15:57:03 ===
Error in process <0.66.0> with exit value:
{badarg,[{erlang,list_to_float,["hello"],[]},
         {erl_eval,do_apply,6,[{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,674}]},
         {erl_eval,expr,5,[{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,438}]},
         {erl_eval,exprs,5,[{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,122}]}]}
enter a float : 5.2
5.2
5>
```

Comment: Let's say p1 ends and it is monitored by p2 using `MonitorRef = erlang:monitor(process, P1)`. How can p2 use `{'DOWN', MonitorRef, process, P1, Reason}` so p2 can terminate itself?

Comment: Thank you I already understood how to use monitors. Problem is p2 is waiting for an input from the user using `io:get_line()` when p1 ended. So now, I don't know how to end p2 when p1 ends. Thanks nevertheless.

Comment: I just see your edited question and I fear that this answer is not what you expect, you should post a piece of code showing p2 and at least a part of p1.

Comment: If p1 and p2 are different processes, the only solution is to send a message from p1 to p2 before finishing.

Comment: If I understood correctly, p2 needs to listen first by using `receive`. How can I use `receive` to get the message from p1 when p2 is currently using `io:get_line()` to get input from the user?

Comment: I have added a new version. BTW, I don't understand why P2 is another process?

Comment: They are both nodes that asks user for an input then sends each other the input as a message. You can think of p1 as user1 and p2 as user2. User1 is initialized using `init_chat()` while user2 is initialized using `init_chat('user1@host')`. `init_chat()` spawns chat1 and msg1 while `init_chat('user1@host')' spawns chat2 and msg2.

Comment: @wency Hi, it is a little off topic (compare to your question) but I see many troubles in your code snippet. I don't understand what are those chat1 and chat2 functions, what is the usage of the parameter 2 etc... I guess this is an exercise or some homework, and I encourage you to do it by your own, for bigger satisfaction and more fun. I have written a small chat system (heavily commented) and post it at [minichat](https://github.com/pascalchap/minichat). Maybe it can give you some hints.